# Unable to remove CSS class a: hover background-color

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, background-color, css-reset

I've created a CSS class .press-title, however I've been unable to remove the backround color applied on hover.

```
.press-title a:hover { background-color: none; text-decoration: none;}
```

Ideas?

Link is towards the bottom of the page:

http://domdemarcos.com/typography/

EDIT to reflect change made from reply.

Answer (score 28):

Try

```
.press-title a:hover { background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Boom, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is invalid. Firefox throws this message: `Expected identifier for pseudo-class or pseudo-element but found ' '.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.`

It should be:

```
.press-title a:hover
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed, but still no joy.